# Tool for deploy and autoarchive Joomla extension

Tags: joomla

I writing some Joomla 2.5 extensions, and I made some script in Perl which can do 3 things:

- deploy files to Joomla installation,
- collect files of extension from all it's folders in Joomla
  installation to one folder
- archive files to zip

I put it here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/joomlamake/

Now I just wondering if something already existing for do this tasks? I mean, is there some tool which can automatically install extension or extract extension from Joomla folders to zip?

Thank you for ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [AkeebaBackup](https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/akeeba-backup.html), a flexible backup system to handle Joomla backups. If you just want to select specific files from extensions to backup you can have different profiles with *Files and Directories Exclusion*

Comment: Yes, it seems be something similar. Thanx.